# Where can I buy fresh water prawns?

Tags: shellfish

[Seafood Watch](http://www.aquaculturehub.org/profiles/blogs/monterey-bay-aquariums-seafood) persuaded me that I ought to experiment with fresh water prawns in my cooking.

Problem: I'm in central Texas, and I can't find any.  The local fish markets and grocers offer no leads, and I've failed to find any good options for having them shipped on line.

Comment: Probably too localised to be an allowed question here.

Comment: The internet market place is too localised?

Comment: Given the nature of the item, which has a very short lifespan if not frozen, and that you state your location.  It would have to be relatively close to you.  You could find a US shipper who will use a frozen cooler pack on overnight air (very expensive), but still you could not ship such a thing internationally; which localises the question to a single country at best, and more likely only Texas and surrounding states would be sensible.  There are supposed to be hatcheries in Texas, so you should be able to find something.

Comment: @orbling - Just to give you an idea of what happens, a large proportion of the prawns caught in the North Sea are shipped to factories in Thailand for processing. There are specialised ships which can transport seafoods internationally - all it takes is for someone to hire a large vessel. You are unlikely to see this happening in US because import tariffs keep the profits down.

Comment: @James Barrie: Living not far from the North Sea, I am aware of the fishing boats with onboard freezers.  But the OP was asking about *Fresh Water* Prawns.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that a lot of this seafood naming is odd sometimes. Prawn is often used to refer to what we used to call shrimp.

In the UK I get these in brine from my local supermarket, marked "krabben im lake" or something similar ...